# Ulink2 does support Realview Debugger JTAG?

Tags: jtag, rvds

i'm using at91rm9200 mpu with metrowerks code warrior

i'm curious that realview ulink2 jtag does support realview debugger

but i have not found related documents for realview debugger v3.1 which jtag can be compatible..

i'm having trouble with buy jtag for RVDS ICE ..

anyone help.. thanks

search googling...

but there is no doc